# SQL query loops twice through each row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I trigger my stored procedure from a web app, it loops twice and creates two identical entries of the same row. I cannot work out why :/

The query is supposed to `INSERT` (re-schedule) all submitted rows. It uses a cursor to go through each row and `SELECT`, then `INSERT`, the correct data from/for each row.

Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [cil].[executeCIL_updateComplDate_And_ReSchedule]
    @equipID INT,
    @date DATE,
    @ip VARCHAR(15)
AS   
    /* add completion date */
    UPDATE cil.schedule 
    SET completionDate = CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS SMALLDATETIME), 
        complIP = @ip
    WHERE schedule.id IN (SELECT schedule.id 
                          FROM cil.schedule
                          LEFT JOIN cil.task ON cil.schedule.taskFK = cil.task.id
                          --WHERE CAST(scheduledDate AS DATE)<=CAST(GetDate() AS DATE)
                          WHERE CAST(scheduledDate as DATE) = @date
                            AND completionDate IS NULL
                            AND result IS NOT NULL
                            AND equipFK = @equipID);

    /* reschedule tasks */
    DECLARE @nextTaskID AS INT;
    DECLARE @nextScheduledDate AS DATETIME2(6);
    DECLARE @nextRotaCycle AS INT;

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT taskFK, scheduledDate, rotaCycle
        FROM cil.schedule 
        LEFT JOIN cil.task ON cil.schedule.taskFK = cil.task.id
        WHERE completionDate = CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS SMALLDATETIME)
          AND equipFK = @equipID;

    OPEN db_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @nextTaskID, @nextScheduledDate, @nextRotaCycle;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        --Do stuff with scalar values
        INSERT INTO cil.schedule (taskFK, scheduledDate, rotaCycle)
        VALUES (@nextTaskID, 
                DATEADD(dd, @nextRotaCycle, @nextScheduledDate),
                @nextRotaCycle)

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @nextTaskID, @nextScheduledDate, 
@nextRotaCycle;
    END;

    CLOSE db_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
GO
```

Comment: does the procedure work standalone?

Comment: if you would run the query from the cursor, are you sure it does not have doubles in the resultset ?

Comment: Why oh why use a cursor here? Think in batches, not in loops when working in SQL Server. Basically, the opposite of python.

Comment: there is also no need for a cursor here, you can write an insert statement and feed it with the query that you have in your cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have duplicates caused by a join of the query of the cursor

If you run this query externally, in SSMS, will it produce only the one row?

```
SELECT taskFK, scheduledDate, rotaCycle
FROM cil.schedule 
LEFT JOIN cil.task ON cil.schedule.taskFK=cil.task.id
WHERE completionDate=CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS SMALLDATETIME)
AND equipFK=@equipID ;
```

and doubles comes from a table task.
If this table is not in use, consider to remove it

Comment: Oh I see, if I have missed task completion 2 days ago, and do it today, the SP will add 1 day to the scheduled date, and create another task which will be for yesterday, now I execute this one, but my completionDate matches 2 rows, because of the miss.... So the stored procedure works ok, it is selected everything that matches the criteria, doesnt get triggered twice as I initially thought..... Now, how do I go around this issue, where I execute the same task ID twice in the same day due to a miss....

Comment: @michal - This answer seems to have solved the question you originally asked. You should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark to the left. If you now need help with this new question you have, you should post a new question with the appropriate details. You can link back to this question from there if you need to.

Comment: @Alexander Volok, thanks for your help, I have now added a check if the date is older than 2 days, it will reschedule for today instead of for the past.